How can i solve Wampserver random error 500 on requests
i get random error 500 on a local server that has wamp. I don't know what to do anymore to get rid of those random 500. I have the same app on a cloud server and it works perfect no error 500. For example in 2h with 30 devices i get like 30 error 500, with 60 devices i get 200 error 500 in same interval. What settings i should try? php and apache logs dont have any errors.
It's not a php code problem, it's some server configration or resources but i don't know what variables i should check.

If you're getting a 500 error when calling a PHP script, there definitely should be something in the php or apache error log.

I don't know what to do anymore to get rid of those random 500...find out what the actual error messages are (it should be in your PHP log, or possibly your Apache log) and then fix the issues. Just like any other error. A 500 error just indicates that the server crashed, it doesn't tell you why it crashed - that's what your error logs are for. So we can't tell you what to do based on only the generic 500 error code.  If there's nothing in your logs, it probably indicates you haven't configured PHP error logging properly - so that's likely to be your first task.

php and apache logs dont have any errors Unlikely unless you turned error reporting OFF!! Make sure when you click the "W" wampmanager icon and select menus like this wampmanager->PHP->PHP Settings that you see a green tick beside display_errors and log_errors

Also make sure error_log ="c:/wamp64/logs/php_error.log" is set in the php.ini You can edit the correct ini file if you do wampmanager->PHP->php.ini(apache module) I assume you are not using [FCGI - CLI]` but if you are check that file

since it's random and i only get error 500 on wamp but on cloud not it's not from php, it's some configuration or resources probably but i don't know what should i set, my php error log is enabled but it does not return any errors.

As RiggsFolly says, please check you've configured the correct php.ini. A 500 error should always log something, somewhere, if your setup is correct. We can't see into your machine so it's difficult to suggest where else to look.

P.s. it won't be random. Computers aren't random. There will be pattern, once you can see some logs and then do some relevant debugging
